# What's the difference between command and function?

Tags: functions

As I know, both of them can do quite the same things, but one should `call` to invoke and other one should use `execute` to invoke.

But whats the difference between `command` and `function`? when should I use one and other?

Comment: Clarification: you don’t always need call for a function (automatic when an expression is expected) and you don’t always need execute for a command (only when doing string interpolation).

Answer (score 6):

Think it as "shell scripting": "Command" is a word that stands at the start of command-line. What follows a command is either "string parameter(s)" or "expression(s)" (that is essentially "evaluate-able" string parameter). Commands never return anything and hence they cannot be evaluated (except something like `:h execute()` but it really counts as "redirection", not as "evaluation").

"Function" in VimScript is simply a special sort of "expression". Therefore no function may take place at command-line start. All functions return a value and so, unlike commands, they may stand on the RHS of assignment.

So it follows that one is able to invoke commands directly: `:SomeCommand some args`; but calling a function requires starting from some command able to evaluate expression(s), e.g. `:call MyFunction(1, 2, 3)`.

So, apart from syntactical differences, you can use them interchangeably, but from practical point of view commands are easier to type for an end-user, while creating a long command implies all those complicated rules about command line continuation, command separation, command line specials expansion and so on. Also, functions provide local variables and auto-loading features. So typical solution is to create a command that calls internal implementation function.